# C# not an event

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I have a problem- in my program, after menuitem is click i use void something:

```
    private void aToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        something(sender, e);
    }
```

This function runs long, so my application can't do anything else in this time. What can i do?

But if i use folderBrowserDialog in function something and i use selectedpath from it in another function?

Answer (score 7):

Use a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) component.

Comment: +1.  You will want to run it on a separate thread, so the UI can continue responding to user events, without seeming "locked up" for a long period of time.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should get to know the [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Aside from MSND Joseph Albahari's [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/threading.pdf) is a excellent resource

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the code which executes 'something' is on the *UI Thread*, which is responsible for processing drawing, mouse clicks, etc. If you want the UI to be responsive while your program is processing 'something' you need to have that happen on a different thread. (So that the UI thread can do its work.)

BackgroundWorker is a good way to solve that problem. I would recommend: [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct.aspx)